# How to compare aggregated field in doctrine 2 with use of queryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am learning symfony2 and doctrine2.
There is error in my query and I am unable to find solution. I want to know how to compare aggregated column with the use of queryBuilder.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('SviplAdminBundle:CouponHolder');

            $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('ch');
            $qb = $qb->select(array('ch.id'))
            ->addSelect($qb->expr()->concat(
                $qb->expr()->concat(
                                'ch.full_name', 
                                $qb->expr()->concat(
                                    $qb->expr()->literal(' ('), 
                                    'ch.refer_owner_code'
                                    )
                                ), 
                                $qb->expr()->literal(')')
                                ).' AS HIDDEN name'
                            )
            ->where('ch.id > 0')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('name', $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$this->get('request')->query->get('q').'%')))
            ->getQuery();
```

above query return following error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 164: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatey, you can't "reuse" aggregated field within `WHERE` clause. You need to recreate it. This is `MySQL`'s limitation. On the other hand, aggregated field ***can*** be used in `GROUP`, `HAVING` and `ORDER` clauses.

The being said, you cannot use `name` in `andWhere` function call. Try replacing it with `ch.full_name` in order to determine if that's the problematic part. If it is, then you need to either:

- repeat concat expression from `SELECT` or
- as you're using `Expr` class, isolate concat into separate variable and reuse it.
- use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` (inefficient)

---

```
$aggr_field = $qb->expr()->concat(
'ch.full_name', 
$qb->expr()->concat(
    $qb->expr()->literal(' ('), 
    'ch.refer_owner_code'
)
), 
$qb->expr()->literal(')')
).' AS HIDDEN name'
);


$qb = $qb->select(array('ch.id'))->andSelect($aggr_field)
>where('ch.id > 0')->andWhere($aggr_field)->getQuery()
```

Comment: thanks problem solved by changing little code provided by you